# String Index out of range for LCS in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the longest common subsequence and with the code below I get `string Index out of range` error.  Not able to figure out why ?

```
def lcs(s1, s2):
    if any((s1, s2)) is None:
        return 0

    if s1[-1] == s2[-1]:
        return 1 + lcs(s1[:len(s1) - 1], s2[:len(s2) - 1])

    return max(lcs(s1, s2[:len(s2) - 1]), lcs(s2, s1[:len(s1) - 1]))

print(lcs("ABDER", "ADFRTY"))
```

Comment: `any()` will never return `None`. Try `if not (s1 and s2): return 0`.

Comment: cool ! that worked but can you tell me why `if s1 is None or s2 is None ` didn't work ?

Comment: Because they're not `None`, they're empty strings `''`.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the misuse of `any()` (and for cleanliness, using the fact that negative indices for strings are counted from the end) makes this print `3`.

```
def lcs(s1, s2):
    if not (s1 and s2):
        return 0

    if s1[-1] == s2[-1]:
        return 1 + lcs(s1[:-1], s2[:-1])

    return max(lcs(s1, s2[:-1]), lcs(s2, s1[:-1]))


print(lcs("ABDER", "ADFRTY"))
```